# Did jodi-vim not support pip installed package?

Tags: jedi-vim

I install python with brew and python site-package directory is /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages.

I try go to method definitions using d.

But it prompt:

```
jedi Couldn't find any definitions for this
```

Then I enter `<leader>d` in socket.socket(), it jump to `/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/socket.py`. So I think vim-jedi works Ok, but it don't local other directory.

How can I fix the bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jedi supports pip. I just answered this question on Jedi's issue tracker: https://github.com/davidhalter/jedi-vim/issues/518.

You might also have issues with MacVIM. You wouldn't be the first one. A lot of people had to reinstall it with homebrew or recompile it.